# how can make wavy line like spelling in data grid c#

Tags: c#, winforms

When the user makes a new grid, I want to show a wavy line like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOTMa.png]

How can I make it? Currenlty, I'm draw it by calling `DrawLine`, but it takes long time to finish it.

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics l = e.Graphics;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        l.DrawLine(p ,10 ,5,5,0);
        l.DrawLine(p, 10, 5, 15, 0);
        l.DrawLine(p, 20, 5, 15, 0);
        l.DrawLine(p, 20, 5, 25, 0);
        l.DrawLine(p, 30, 5, 25, 0);
        l.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: try drawing the line in CellPainting event of datagridview, or override the grid's OnCellPainting method. Also, you shouldn't dispose of the Graphics object that you got from PaintEventArgs, instead you should dispose of the Pen object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a handler for `DataGridView.CellPainting` event.

```
dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;
```

Here the implementation. Note: The lines are outside the 'white box' of cells.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGridView) sender;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 || e.RowIndex != (dg.RowCount - 1))
        return;

    using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
    {
        var cellBounds = e.CellBounds;

        const int size = 2;
        var pts = new List<Point>();
        var h = false;
        for (int i = cellBounds.Left; i <= cellBounds.Right; i += size,h = !h)
        {
            pts.Add(
                new Point
                {
                    X = i,
                    Y = h ? cellBounds.Bottom : cellBounds.Bottom + size
                });
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawLines(p, pts.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: DataGridView]

I hope it helps.